# Selecting rows using a variable with multiple values

Tags: sql, toad

I'm new at this and I can't seem to find the right answer on the internet since there are so many ways to create an SQL statement. But basically, this is what I want to do.

The user fills up a form:

> Names : Name1, Name2, Name3

How do I select the rows in the table where the names are 'Name1', 'Name2' and 'Name3'?
I know that in TOAD we can query one value like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE Names = ?
```

How should the query be if I want to enter multiple values for Names? Can SQL search an array of values for a single variable?

EDIT: I pressed enter when I was creating the post, so the first post was incomplete. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I've been reading on "EXISTS" and I could have used this instead! :)